# Alexa Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit

I have a Raspberry PI  model  B+  and I was thinking of integrating it to Alexa Voice Service. So I was able to manage my Raspberry PI and Alexa  Voice Service  until the part that Alexa  says hello. In order to achieve this I used also PC108 media USB external sound card.  So I’m getting both  input and output from my plug-in microphone or my mini jack audio output to speaker. The thing is that something is missing in order to work .What do I have to do in order to make Alexa listen ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At re:Invent 2016 they had a workshop on doing this.  Take a look at [the slides](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/aws-reinvent-2016-workshop-build-an-alexaenabled-product-with-raspberry-pi-alx204) from the session and the [workshop instructions](https://avs-workshop.github.io/).  We used a simple USB microphone and sound is built into the Pi.  The [sample app](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app) is still being updated so it should be good to go.

This was with a Pi3 but the basics should still be the same.

Comment: Thanks for replying is such a short time. 
There are differences between  Raspberry Pi model B+ and model 3.
Also I changed the  sound built-in output and now is in my external USB card were also I get the input from my microphone. Probably what I’m looking here is a voice recognition driver in order to make Alexa listen.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PiCroft that is an image of Mycroft a open source assistant it's just burn it on a sdcard and use

https://mycroft.ai/mycroft-now-available-raspberry-pi-image/

if you want to create skills https://docs.mycroft.ai/skill.creation